# Cannot use struct that implements interface

Tags: go

code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type implementation struct {
    d []int
}

func (impl *implementation) getData() interface{} {
    return impl.d
}

type phase struct{}

type data interface {
    getData() interface{}
}

func MakeIntDataPhase() *phase {
    return &phase{}
}

func (p *phase) run(population []data) []data {
    return nil
}

func main() {
    var population []implementation
    MyPhase := MakeIntDataPhase()
    fmt.Println(MyPhase.run(population))

}
```

When running following code in playground I got following error: `prog.go:30:25: cannot use population (type []implementation) as type []data in argument to MyPhase.run`

I am new to golang and I don't understand why is this happening?

Struct `implementation` implements method `getData()` from `data` interface. Isn't it enough to use  a slice of `implementation` in `run` method?

Where my reasoning is wrong?

Comment: That's not how slices work. See https://golang.org/doc/faq#convert_slice_of_interface

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems counter-intuitive but `[]data` is of a different type to `[]implementation` because of how slice types are represented in Go.

This is actually discussed in the the [Go Wiki](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/InterfaceSlice)

Edit: Consider this

```
var impl []*implementation
var data []data = impl
```

The compiler will complain with

```
cannot use impl (type []*implementation) as type []data in assignment
```

It's more code but you actually have to create a slice of your interface as what the comments in this thread recommends, like so:

```
var impl []*implementation
var data []data

// assuming impl already has values
for _, v := range impl {
    data = append(data, v)
}
```